# Parametrisation of an arbitrary scalar function f(r)

Tags: integration

I am integrating along a straight line from $\vec r_0$ to $\vec r$ which is parametrised by $\vec r^\prime = \lambda\vec r$ with $0\le\lambda\le1$. Thus $d\vec r^\prime=d\lambda\vec r$ and hence:$$\phi(\vec r)=\int_0^\vec r \vec a(\vec r^\prime)\cdot d\vec r^\prime=\int_{\lambda=0}^{\lambda=1} \vec a(\lambda\vec r)\cdot \vec r d\lambda$$

The vector field I am using is $\vec a=\vec rf(r)$ where $f(r)$ is an arbitrary function of $r=|\vec r|$.

Therefore, $$\phi(\vec r)=\int_{\lambda=0}^{\lambda=1} \vec a(\lambda\vec r)\cdot \vec r d\lambda$$
$$=\int_{0}^{1} \lambda\vec rf(\lambda r)\cdot \vec r d\lambda\: [\star]$$
$$=\int_{0}^{1} \lambda^2(\vec r\cdot \vec r)f(r) d\lambda\:[\star\star]$$
$$=(\vec r\cdot \vec r)f(r)\int_{0}^{1} \lambda^2 d\lambda $$
$$=\frac{1}{3}(\vec r\cdot \vec r)f(r)=\frac{1}{3}r^2f(r)$$

I believe I have mistreated the $f(\lambda r)$ function in $[\star]$ or $[\star\star]$. I do not know how to work with the parametrisation of the $f(r)$ function. Can someone explain how to treat this function?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the integral $\vec{r}$ is a constant. That means that $r = |\vec{r}|$ is also constant. In the step $[*]$ to $[**]$ you cannot move the $\lambda$ outside the argument of $f$ in general. This means that it is not possible to simplify as much as you have done. You can do $$\int_0^1\lambda \vec{r}f(\lambda r) \cdot \vec{r} d\lambda =  (\vec{r}\cdot \vec{r})\lambda \int_0^1 f(\lambda r) d\lambda.$$ Here you can note that $\vec{r} \cdot \vec{r} = r^2$ and you can change variable to $x = \lambda r$ giving $$r^2 \lambda \int_0^r f(x) \frac{dx}{r} = r \lambda \int_0^r f(x) dx.$$

Comment: So is there a way I can evaluate the integral $$r^2\int_{0}^{1} \lambda f(\lambda r) d\lambda$$

Comment: You can if you know $f$ but not otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that I will have to leave the integral as it is unless I do not have the specific function that $f(r)$ represents